# Creating XML Documents with GDataXML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, ios5

I don't know how can I create XML document using GDataXML nor I could find any good link which can help me.Please tell me how can I perform this or give some good link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml tutorial. It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First create and store the xml value to a string.
Then use the following method to create the xml file in the document directory.

//Method writes a string to a xml file

```
-(void) writeToXMLFile:(NSString *)content
{

    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
   NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/xmlfile.xml",documentsDirectory];

   //save content to the documents directory
   [content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

}
```

Comment: I don't know how can I "First create and store the xml value to a string" implement this part.I'm new to XML.

Comment: @subham: please check the http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml for more

Comment: @subham: NSString *str = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><name> Midhun </name>"; simple xml using nsstring

Comment: @MidhunMP Where should I write this code in raywenderlich's example?