# creating XML using GDataXML in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios7, gdataxml

I want to create a xml in this format using GDataXml.

```
<Response>
    <Question Number ="1" OptionID="4" Comments=""/>
    <Question Number ="2" OptionID="3" Comments=""/>
    <Question Number ="3" OptionID="5" Comments=""/>
    <Question Number ="4" OptionID="6" Comments=""/>
</Response>
```

Please help!!. I quite novice in Objective C

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.i followed this link

https://github.com/skjolber/xswi

My code is

```
XMLWriter* objXmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc]init];

 [objXmlWriter writeStartDocumentWithEncodingAndVersion:@"UTF-8" version:@"1.0"];
[objXmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Response"];
[objXmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Question"];
[objXmlWriter writeAttribute:@"Number" value:@"52"];
[objXmlWriter writeAttribute:@"OptionID" value:@"2"];
[objXmlWriter writeAttribute:@"Comments" value:@"Test "];
[objXmlWriter writeEndElement];
[objXmlWriter writeEndElement];
[objXmlWriter writeEndDocument];
```

`

Comment: common , as i mentioned before i am quite novice in Objective c and also needed it urgently!!

Comment: still - search 30 seconds -- e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283840/creating-xml-documents-with-gdataxml?rq=1 -- **oh and note I didn't downvote anything because you're new to SO** take it as advice only